# Deleting <textarea> tag from Document doc

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am about to parse this url :  http://online.wsj.com/public/page/news-wall-street-heard.html?dsk=y

```
Document jDoc = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();
System.out.println(jDoc1.text());
```

But the output of the second line(above) is all TAGS inside  textarea + text of other tags. Output is like :

```
..
..
<ul class="">
<li><a data-time="1dy" data-frequency="1mi" class="mdm_time">1 Day</a></li>
<li><a data-time="5dy" data-frequency="15mi" class="mdm_time">5 Days</a></li>
..
..
```

All the html is getting printed (of what is inside ) and text of other tags. I either want to remove this tag from Doc or want to get this  as element so that I can remove it by my hand.

Hope, I am able to explain everything clearly. Please help me solve this.

EDIT :

As per suggestion, I did this :

```
System.out.println(jDoc1.select("textarea"));
```

And output comes is :

```
    textarea id="wsj_autocomplete_template" style="display:none">   

    &lt;div&gt;
            &lt;div class=&quot;acHeadline hidden&quot;  &gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div class=&quot;dropdownContainerClass&quot;&gt;
                &lt;div class=&quot;suggestionblock hidden&quot; templateType=&quot;C1&quot;&gt;    

....
...
..
```

Certainly it is selecting the textarea, but is not able to parse inner elements. possibly due to &lt instead of < tag. Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the entire text area tag use `doc.select("textarea").remove();`. Or if you want to get the content of textarea use `doc.select("textarea").text()`. Note here i'm using the `text()` method instead of `toString()` or `html()` methods. This gives the exact text rather than html escape codes.

Again if you want to manipulate this html you can parse it again like `Document textareaDoc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(doc.select("textarea").text());`

Example

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class WSJParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "http://online.wsj.com/public/page/news-wall-street-heard.html?dsk=y";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            //doc.select("textarea").remove(); // Removes the entire text area tag
            Document textareaDoc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(doc.select("textarea").text());
            System.out.println(textareaDoc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is this

```
Elements textareas = Jsoup.connect(url1).get().select("textarea");

for (Element textarea : textareas) {
    Elements elements = textarea.select("*"); 
    for (Element element : elements) {
        System.out.println(element.ownText());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I edit question based on your suggestion. Please refer.